# How to display PDFs as images in a partial view (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, bitmap

Okay. This is what I have. I have a pdf file that is converted into a byte[] and saved to a Db.
What I want to do is to convert the pdf file into an image and display it in a partial view as a popup.
I was able to achieve this, but there was a couple of problems.
1- The converted image had low quality 
2- the process was slow

This is my code (I used TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer library to do the conversion, don't mind if you guys recommend a better library)

```
var doc = service.GetAttachmentById(documentId);
            ViewAttachmentViewModel model = new ViewAttachmentViewModel();
            if (doc.Extension.ToLower().Trim() == ".pdf")
            {
                // convert pdf to image
                try
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(doc.Content))
                    {
                        Document m = new Document(stream);
                        Page p = m.Pages[0];
                        bitmap = new Bitmap((int)p.Width, (int)p.Height);
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                        {
                            p.Draw(g);
                        }
                    }
                    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                    byte[] cont = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
                    model = new ViewAttachmentViewModel
                    {
                        Id = documentId,
                        Content = cont,
                        FileName = doc.Title
                    };

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // handle exception here;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                model = new ViewAttachmentViewModel
                {
                    Id = documentId,
                    Content = doc.Content,
                    FileName = doc.Title
                };
            }
            return PartialView("_AttachmentPopupViewer", model);
```

partial view:

```
  @{
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Content);
        var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
    }

    <img src="@imgSrc" />
```

Comment: For the issue of the image being small: check what `p.Width` and `p.Height` mean, perhaps they are defined as a unit such as mm. In that case just multiply them by a suitable factor. For the issue of speed: nothing I can suggest, and the aforementioned change would probably make it even slower...

Comment: I other pdf -> image libraries for .NET I've used, there is usually some sort of DPI setting which can be set to improve image quality. This does however come at a cost of a far higher file size.

Comment: https://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfrasterizer/help/convert-to-raster-formats.htm 4.3. Set the resolution

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [PDFJS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) in my project. it works pretty well. give it a try

It's not converting pdf to image but it's a tool for parsing and rendering PDFs in your website